# Obtener valor en json con varios stdClass

Tags: php, json, mariadb

Tengo una tabla en una base de datos que tiene como contenido archivos json. Con php hago consulta para obtener el json que se ve así (obtenido con `print_r()`):

```
{"platform":"Moodle","contextActivities":{"category":[{"id":"http://vocab.xapi.fr/categories/learning-unit","objectType":"Activity","definition":{"type":"http://vocab.xapi.fr/activities/granularity-level"}},{"objectType":"Activity","id":"http://vocab.xapi.fr/categories/vle-profile","definition":{"type":"http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/profile"}}],"grouping":[{"objectType":"Activity","id":"http://www.di.panconpalta.com.mx","definition":{"type":"http://vocab.xapi.fr/activities/system"}}],"parent":[{"objectType":"Activity","id":"http://www.di.panconpalta.com.mx/xapi/activities/course/5b24f650-3234-47d1-9c2d-b09d5d08557c","definition":{"type":"http://vocab.xapi.fr/activities/course"}}]},"extensions":{"http://vocab.xapi.fr/extensions/platform-event":"\\mod_hvp\\event\\course_module_viewed"}},"timestamp":"2019-07-16T17:13:22-04:00","actor":{"objectType":"Agent","account":{"homePage":"http://www.di.panconpalta.com.mx","name":"77e56417-3e9a-4d1a-840b-b89cce9710c8"}},"verb":{"id":"http://vocab.xapi.fr/verbs/navigated-in"},"object":{"objectType":"Activity","id":"http://www.di.panconpalta.com.mx/xapi/activities/hvp/c3c2ffec-74cf-4e51-ba77-2cfacd276b38","definition":{"type":"http://vocab.xapi.fr/activities/interactive-video","name":{"es":"Estrategias de apoyo"},"extensions":{"http://vocab.xapi.fr/extensions/platform-concept":"hvp-interactive-video","http://vocab.xapi.fr/extensions/concept-family":"resource"}}},"stored":"2019-07-16T21:13:22.4585Z","authority":{"objectType":"Agent","account":{"homePage":"http://trax.test","name":"traxlrs"}},"id":"7b33d7e2-46e4-39dc-b4c6-e1d7473c64a2","version":"1.0.0"}
```

Luego, decodifico el contenido como un archivo json con la función `json_decode()`. Entonces el json queda así:

```
stdClass Object ( [context] => stdClass Object ( [platform] => Moodle [contextActivities] => stdClass Object ( [category] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => http://vocab.xapi.fr/categories/learning-unit [objectType] => Activity [definition] => stdClass Object ( [type] => http://vocab.xapi.fr/activities/granularity-level ) ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [objectType] => Activity [id] => http://vocab.xapi.fr/categories/vle-profile [definition] => stdClass Object ( [type] => http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/profile ) ) ) [grouping] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [objectType] => Activity [id] => http://www.di.panconpalta.com.mx [definition] => stdClass Object ( [type] => http://vocab.xapi.fr/activities/system ) ) ) [parent] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [objectType] => Activity [id] => http://www.di.panconpalta.com.mx/xapi/activities/course/5b24f650-3234-47d1-9c2d-b09d5d08557c [definition] => stdClass Object ( [type] => http://vocab.xapi.fr/activities/course ) ) ) ) [extensions] => stdClass Object ( [http://vocab.xapi.fr/extensions/platform-event] => \mod_hvp\event\course_module_viewed ) ) [timestamp] => 2019-07-16T17:13:22-04:00 [actor] => stdClass Object ( [objectType] => Agent [account] => stdClass Object ( [homePage] => http://www.di.panconpalta.com.mx [name] => 77e56417-3e9a-4d1a-840b-b89cce9710c8 ) ) [verb] => stdClass Object ( [id] => http://vocab.xapi.fr/verbs/navigated-in ) [object] => stdClass Object ( [objectType] => Activity [id] => http://www.di.panconpalta.com.mx/xapi/activities/hvp/c3c2ffec-74cf-4e51-ba77-2cfacd276b38 [definition] => stdClass Object ( [type] => http://vocab.xapi.fr/activities/interactive-video [name] => stdClass Object ( [es] => Estrategias de apoyo ) [extensions] => stdClass Object ( [http://vocab.xapi.fr/extensions/platform-concept] => hvp-interactive-video [http://vocab.xapi.fr/extensions/concept-family] => resource ) ) ) [stored] => 2019-07-16T21:13:22.4585Z [authority] => stdClass Object ( [objectType] => Agent [account] => stdClass Object ( [homePage] => http://trax.test [name] => traxlrs ) ) [id] => 7b33d7e2-46e4-39dc-b4c6-e1d7473c64a2 [version] => 1.0.0 )
```

Y cuando intento obtener un valor para insertarlo en una tabla, no aparece nada. A continuación el extracto de código:

```
                            <tbody>
                        <?php
                        $sql = "select * from trax_xapiserver_statements order by id DESC";

                        $estado = ejecutarComando($sql);
                        $num=0;
                        while($row = $estado->fetch_assoc()) { 
                            $array = json_decode($row["data"]);
                        ?>

                        <tr class="odd gradeX">
                            <td><?php echo $num+=1;?></td>
                            <td><?php echo substr($row["data"], 0, 100)."...";?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $array->objectType;?></td> //Aquí es donde debería mostrarse el resultado ObjectType
                            <td><?php echo $row["voided"];?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row["created_at"];?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row["updated_at"];?></td>
                            <td style="text-align:center">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <a href="view.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></a>
                                    <a href="download.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                        </tbody>
```

En resumen, necesito obtener cada uno de los valores del array generado del json y no puedo, además que no sé exactamente lo que es stdClass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las stdClass son un tipo de variable que deben ser manipuladas como objetos. 
Es por esto que muchas veces son dificiles de manipular.

EJ:

```
//Si queremos obtener el parametro ["voided"] **NO** debemos hacer $var["voided"]
//Debemos hacer $var->voided
```

Mi recomendacion personal es que hagas

```
json_decode($tuJson, true);
```

Esto convertira tu json en un array associativo que es mucho mas facil de manipular, ya que es un array de toda la vida, pero con keys alfanumericas.